# Found this error while importing sql file in PhpMyadmin wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin

Error
SQL query: Documentation

```
--
-- Database: `evento`
--
DELIMITER $$--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `location_status` ( IN  `reservation_date` DATETIME, IN  `location_id` INT( 11 ) ) READS SQL DATA SELECT  '$$'$$
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1046 - No database selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a database before running your query (or importing the file, I'm not sure which you're trying to do). From the left-hand navigation pane, just click on a database name, then you can run this SQL to create your procedure. Otherwise phpMyAdmin doesn't know which database to run the query on since it's not defined in the SQL itself.